# How to understand a database layout?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I want to understand a database layout.

It has 180 tables.

I only know the high level use case: Owncloud (File Hosting Server. Can be compared to DropBox).

How to understand the database layout?

How to identify the most important tables?

Is there a tool which helps me to understand the layout?

At the moment am interested in two facts:

- ForeignKey Relations: It would be nice to have graph
- Number of rows in the table.

I use PostgreSQL 9.5.5

Answer (score 1):

[SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net) is a free piece of software that enables you to output html documentation of your databases, one of the many vendors it supports is PostgreSQL.